# C# Setting load and save

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I trying to load and save setting with this code but when I closing and rerun program the settings not loaded. By default the settings was blank. I have no error.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      txtUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Username;
      txtPassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
      Properties.Settings.Default.Username = txtUsername.Text;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Password = txtPassword.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  Properties.Settings.Default.Username = txtUsername.Text;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Password = txtPassword.Text;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: you have to save the setting after you set it or it will not be retained in the seetings file.

Comment: @IEnumerable wouldn't that make more sense in your answer, instead of a comment...

Answer (score 3):

[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx)
If you want to persist the changes to the settings between application sessions, call the Save method, as shown below:;

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You need to call Save() at the end of `Form1_FormClosing`