# How can I save settings to a text file and read them back?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace StopwatchTimer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string settingsPath = "Settings";

        private string settingsFileName = "settings.txt";
        private static readonly Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        private long diff = 0, previousTicks = 0, ticksDisplayed = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            richTextBox1.TabStop = false;
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            richTextBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            richTextBox1.Enter += RichTextBox1_Enter;

            settingsPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath), settingsPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(settingsPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(settingsPath);

            settingsFileName = Path.Combine(settingsPath, settingsFileName);
            if (!File.Exists(settingsFileName))
                File.Create(settingsFileName);

            string[] settings =  File.ReadAllText(settingsFileName).Split(',');
            if(settings.Length > 0)
            {

            }
    }       radioButton1.Checked = true;
}
```

I didn't write yet to the text file. I want for example to write to the text file the radioButton1 and radioButton2 states somewhere else in the code and then reading the states back when running the application.

So I'm using Split with ',' but how do I check if the value when reading back is belong to the radioButton1 or radioButton2 or maybe a textBox or a button1 ?

Comment: You could use XML here with XMLReader / XMLWriter, and tag each entry with the controlname, rather than writing plaintext strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in winforms settings:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  Properties.Settings.Default.Username = txtUsername.Text;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Password = txtPassword.Text;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

[C# Setting load and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238398/c-sharp-setting-load-and-save)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp

Comment: WinForms settings is generally a bad idea. If the application is ever rebuilt or updated, all settings will be lost. Additionally, if you want to save more than 1 set of settings, virtually any other method is preferable.